# Intuitive explanation of Nyquist rate?

Tags: frequency, signal-processing, radio-frequency

Is there an intuitive way to understand Nyquist rate (i.e., that, in order to prevent loss, an analog signal must be digitized at a rate twice as high as the highest frequency component of the signal). I have sort of a picture in my mind of having to “line up” with the dips and peaks of a signal (hopefully that makes sense), but I’m not sure if that’s a “healthy” way to think about this.

Comment: In case you don’t get an answer here, there is a dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: That is exactly the right way to think about it. For example suppose you take 10 samples per second. Draw pictures of what happens for sine waves with frequency 4, 5, and 6 Hz. The samples for 4 and 6 Hz will look identical.

Comment: @alephzero - Think of making your comment an answer.